# Cannot display UIUserNotificationActions in foreground (default context)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am trying to get a set of user notification actions to display with more than 2 buttons.  The notification itself utilises the minimal context when app is in the background and this works fine.

When the notification is called while in the foreground, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is called as per the documentation on the UILocalNotification class.

How is an alert with more than two buttons (provided by the default context of the action category) ever displayed?

The code below follows the documentation for using more than 2 buttons but only calls application:didReceiveLocalNotification: when the app is in the foreground:

```
//  Selecting YES activates the app in the foreground
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *actionYes = [ UIMutableUserNotificationAction new ];
actionYes.identifier = @"actionYes";
actionYes.title = @"Yes";
actionYes.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
actionYes.destructive = NO;
actionYes.authenticationRequired = NO;

//  Selecting NO activates the app in the background
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *actionNo = [ UIMutableUserNotificationAction new ];
actionNo.identifier = @"actionNo";
actionNo.title = @"No";
actionNo.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
actionNo.destructive = NO;
actionNo.authenticationRequired = NO;

//  Selecting NEVER activates the app in the background
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *actionNever = [ UIMutableUserNotificationAction new ];
actionNever.identifier = @"actionNever";
actionNever.title = @"Never";
actionNever.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
actionNever.destructive = YES;
actionNever.authenticationRequired = NO;

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory = [ UIMutableUserNotificationCategory new ];
actionCategory.identifier = @"actionCategory";
[ actionCategory setActions: @[ actionYes, actionNo, actionNever ] forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault ];
[ actionCategory setActions: @[ actionNo, actionYes ] forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal ];

NSSet *categories = [ NSSet setWithObjects: actionCategory, nil] ;
UIUserNotificationType notificationType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [ UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: notificationType categories: categories ];

//  The categories have to be registered for notification settings to the app
[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] registerUserNotificationSettings: notificationSettings ];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [ UILocalNotification new ];
localNotification.fireDate = [ NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 5.0 ];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Testing user notifications message";
localNotification.category =  @"actionCategory"; //  Same as category identifier
[ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] scheduleLocalNotification: localNotification ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than 2 buttons, the user has to select "Alerts" as opposed to "Banners" in the app settings menu.  The alert will have an Options button that displays the buttons in a list between Open and Close.

The Alert/Banner options cannot be set programmatically.

If an app is in the foreground all notifications will get sent directly to the app delegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification: without exception; this entails that actions cannot be obtained while the app is in the foreground.

I hope this helps anyone else reading through the Apple documentation.

Comment: Do you know how Apple's Reminder app decides whether to use a category of actions with 'Minimal' context or with 'Default' context?